# Get all messages from the same recipient (GMAIL API)

Tags: android, gmail-api

my code :

```
public class HistoriqueActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleAccount mGoogleAccount;
private HistoriquePagerAdapter mHistoriquePagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ArrayList<Message> listMessage;
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.historique);

    this.mHistoriquePagerAdapter = new HistoriquePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    this.mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(mHistoriquePagerAdapter);
    this.mGoogleAccount = GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USED;
    this.listMessage = new ArrayList<>();

    //this line:
    this.listMessage = mGoogleAccount.getmGmail().users().messages().get(mGoogleAccount.getmCredential().getSelectedAccountName(), /* recipient */);

}

}
```

My problème is this line, i don't know how to get all messages with the same recipient, does any function existing to do it?
The Gmail documentation isn't that easy to understand.

Comment: If you want to have a list of messages and not a message in particular, you must use `.list()` function instead `.get()`. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#examples

Comment: Oh ty, but can i get a list of messages with only the same recipient?

Comment: What do you mean by "only the same recipient" ? All messages send by your user to the same email address ?

Comment: "All messages send by your user to the same email address ?" yes !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list` function instead `get` : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

In your case,

```
mGoogleAccount.getmGmail().users().messages().get(mGoogleAccount.getmCredential().getSelectedAccountName(), /* recipient */);
```

becomes

```
mGoogleAccount.getmGmail().users().messages().list(mGoogleAccount.getmCredential().getSelectedAccountName()).setQ("to:address@mail.com").execute();
```

Where `address@mail.com` is the recipient of messages that you want. The argument of `setQ()` is query that you can use on the Gmail client : https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

And obviously, you must initialize your `mGoogleAccount` variable as describe on Gmail API documentation.

Comment: Ty i will try this line ! should i add " .execute(); " ?

Comment: Ty for this answer !